# Что это за модуль src_rc?

Tags: python, pyqt5

После создания виджета в Qt Designer и переноса в Python с помощью pyuic5 в самом конце кода образовался непонятный импорт:
`import src_rc`.
Вопрос: откуда он взялся и зачем он нужен. Если попробовать его установить pip его не находит.
Вот код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1246, 698)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1246, 698))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1246, 698))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background: #191919;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.nav_menu = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.nav_menu.setEnabled(True)
        self.nav_menu.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 269, 698))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.nav_menu.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.nav_menu.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.nav_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(269, 0))
        self.nav_menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.nav_menu.setStyleSheet("border: 0;\n"
"background: #151515;")
        self.nav_menu.setObjectName("nav_menu")
        self.btn_add_folder = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.nav_menu)
        self.btn_add_folder.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(218, 30, 24, 31))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_add_folder.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_add_folder.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_add_folder.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 31))
        self.btn_add_folder.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 31))
        self.btn_add_folder.setText("")
        self.btn_add_folder.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("F:/Projects/Python/.pyqt/Tasker/src/img/add_folder.svg"))
        self.btn_add_folder.setObjectName("btn_add_folder")
        self.logo = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.nav_menu)
        self.logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 142, 52))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.logo.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.logo.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.logo.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(142, 52))
        self.logo.setText("")
        self.logo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/src/img/logo.svg"))
        self.logo.setObjectName("logo")
        self.buttons = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.nav_menu)
        self.buttons.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(23, 93, 219, 583))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.buttons.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.buttons.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.buttons.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(219, 583))
        self.buttons.setTitle("")
        self.buttons.setObjectName("buttons")
        self.btn_menu1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.buttons)
        self.btn_menu1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 219, 37))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_menu1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_menu1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_menu1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(219, 37))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Inter")
        font.setPointSize(-1)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.btn_menu1.setFont(font)
        self.btn_menu1.setStyleSheet("background: #1490AA;\n"
"border-radius: 11px;\n"
"font-family: \'Inter\';\n"
"font-style: normal;\n"
"font-weight: 400;\n"
"font-size: 16px;\n"
"line-height: 19px;\n"
"text-align: left;\n"
"color: #FFFFFF;\n"
"padding: 8px 0 8px 15px;")
        self.btn_menu1.setObjectName("btn_menu1")
        self.btn_menu2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.buttons)
        self.btn_menu2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 47, 219, 37))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_menu2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_menu2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_menu2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(219, 37))
        self.btn_menu2.setStyleSheet("background: #282828;\n"
"border-radius: 11px;\n"
"font-family: \'Inter\';\n"
"font-style: normal;\n"
"font-weight: 400;\n"
"font-size: 16px;\n"
"line-height: 19px;\n"
"text-align: left;\n"
"color: #FFFFFF;\n"
"padding: 8px 0 8px 15px;")
        self.btn_menu2.setObjectName("btn_menu2")
        self.btn_menu3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.buttons)
        self.btn_menu3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 94, 219, 37))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.btn_menu3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.btn_menu3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.btn_menu3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(219, 37))
        self.btn_menu3.setStyleSheet("background: #282828;\n"
"border-radius: 11px;\n"
"font-family: \'Inter\';\n"
"font-style: normal;\n"
"font-weight: 400;\n"
"font-size: 16px;\n"
"line-height: 19px;\n"
"text-align: left;\n"
"color: #FFFFFF;\n"
"padding: 8px 0 8px 15px;")
        self.btn_menu3.setObjectName("btn_menu3")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(269, -20, 977, 719))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.stackedWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.stackedWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.stackedWidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(977, 719))
        self.stackedWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(977, 719))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        self.page_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_4.setObjectName("page_4")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_4)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_menu1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Все задачи"))
        self.btn_menu2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Папка 1"))
        self.btn_menu3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Папка 2"))
import src_rc
```

Comment: Не заморачивайся, начни например - вязать!?

Comment: скорее всего IDE сама автоматически добавила. Если не используется, почему бы не удалить просто.

Comment: Похожий вопрос, хотя название файла другое https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301204/importerror-no-module-named-resource-rc

Comment: @gfd2 да, конечно, просто интересно узнать что это

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это файл в котором хранятся иконки, картинки вставленные на форму через дизайнер.